# Python trace URL get requests - using python script

Tags: python, module, urllib2, httplib

I'm writing a script, to help me do some repetitive testing of a bunch of URLs.

I've written a python method in the script that it opens up the URL and sends a get request. I'm using Requests: HTTP for Humans -http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/- api to handle the http calls.

There's the request.history that returns a list of status codes of the directs. I need to be able to access the particular redirects for those list of 301s. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this - to access and trace what my URLS are redirecting to. I want to be able to access the redirected URLS (status code 301)

Can anyone offer any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Look at the headers. I think the `301` also has a redirect URL header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so when i look at `r.headers` I get a the definition list of header information, nothing telling me about redirects or 301 status.

Comment: does 'r.history' have any more functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm so silly. Here's the answer I was looking for

`r = requests.get("http://someurl")`
`r.history[1].url` will return the URL